# Mudar cor da aplicação Aero

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Como mudo a cor da aplicação .NET/Forms na barra de tarefas do Windows Aero?

[image]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe API documentada. A Microsoft criou as cores da barra de ferramentas no Windows Aero para serem alteradas pelo **usuário** e não pela aplicação.

Entretando, existe a API `DwmSetColorizationParameters`, sem documentação. A recomendação é usá-la porém testar a aplicação em diferentes versões do Windows, para ver se a compatibilidade é de 100%, caso contrário, terá que filtrar o SO ou não usá-la.

Se precisar da validação do SO, talvez possa usar o `System.Environment.OSVersion` para i[dentificar a versão do Windows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5956c04f-072a-406c-ae6a-cc8b3a207936/systemenvironmentosversionversionmajor?forum=csharpgeneral).

Segundo usuários do SOen, ela é compatível com o Windows 7, mas é preciso testar com os posteriores SPs e atualizações.

A classe pronta ficará assim:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DwmManager
{
   private struct DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS
   {
      public uint clrColor;
      public uint clrAfterGlow;
      public uint nIntensity;
      public uint clrAfterGlowBalance;
      public uint clrBlurBalance;
      public uint clrGlassReflectionIntensity;
      public bool fOpaque;
   }

   [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#127", PreserveSig = false)]
   private static extern void DwmGetColorizationParameters(out DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters);

   [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#131", PreserveSig = false)]
   private static extern void DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters,
                                                           bool unknown);

   // Helper method to convert from a Win32 BGRA-format color to a .NET color.
   private static Color BgraToColor(uint color)
   {
      return Color.FromArgb(Int32.Parse(color.ToString("X"), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
   }

   // Helper method to convert from a .NET color to a Win32 BGRA-format color.
   private static uint ColorToBgra(Color color)
   {
      return (uint)(color.B | (color.G << 8) | (color.R << 16) | (color.A << 24));
   }

   // Gets or sets the current color used for DWM glass, based on the user's color scheme.
   public static Color ColorizationColor
   {
      get
      {
         // Call the DwmGetColorizationParameters function to fill in our structure.
         DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters;
         DwmGetColorizationParameters(out parameters);

         // Convert the colorization color to a .NET color and return it.
         return BgraToColor(parameters.clrColor);
      }
      set
      {
         // Retrieve the current colorization parameters, just like we did above.
         DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters;
         DwmGetColorizationParameters(out parameters);

         // Then modify the colorization color.
         // Note that the other parameters are left untouched, so they will stay the same.
         // You can also modify these; that is left as an exercise.
         parameters.clrColor = ColorToBgra(value);

         // Call the DwmSetColorizationParameters to make the change take effect.
         DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref parameters, false);
      }
   }
}
```

Após adicionada ao projeto, é só manipular o `ColorizationColor`.

É importante notar que o [DWM Composition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538(v=vs.85).aspx) é suportado pelo SO e está habilitado antes de executar qualquer uma dessas funções. Para tal, é preciso dessa função:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref bool pfEnabled);
```

[Resposta adaptada daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808712/6241184)